# Using breeze.js I only want to send updated properties for a non-cached entity

Tags: save, entity-framework-6, breeze, entities

I have a scenario where I know the primary key of an entity (retrieved from an unrelated source), and I want to update just 1 property (db column).  I have NOT already retrieved the entity from the database.  If possible I would like to not have to make this extra round trip.

I create the entity using manager.createEntity.
I update one of the properties.
Then set the entityAspect to setModified(); 
When saving changes, all the properties that were not updated are set to their default values, and the generated SQL UPDATE statement attempts to update all mapped columns.

Is there a way to tell breeze to only generate SQL for specific properties/columns?

thanks

Comment: Breeze (on the client) does not generate the SQL; that is done on the server.  What server technologies are you using?

Comment: .net Web API and EF6 with SQL Server

Comment: I figured out a solution but would like to know if if's a supported.  I know that the SQL is generated in EF, but the EF needs to be told what to generate, which is where breeze comes in.  Looking at the JSON is seemed that if the property was in the originalValuesMap then it would be included in the SQL update statement.  If there was no map, then the entire entity would be updated.  So in my example above, after I did all the steps,  I also set the original value: obj.entityAspect.originalValues.myProperty = 0;  (myProperty  is a numeric).  This correctly updated just that column.

Comment: Is this an accepted approach to use with breeze?  I'm manually manipulating the originalValues map to control which columns in the DB get updated.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, the properties of the `originalValuesMap` guide the Breeze server's `ContextProvider` as it prepares the save request. This is documented in the [ContextProvider topic](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/contextprovider).

In your example, you call `setModified` after you've changed the property. All that does is change the `EntityState`; it doesn't create an entry in the client entity's `entityAspect.originalValuesMap` ... therefore the `originalValuesMap` sent to the server is empty.

> I'm a little surprised that the `EFContextProvider.SaveChanges` prepared an EF update of the entire entity. I would have guessed that it simply ignored the entity all together. I'm making a mental note to investigate that myself. Not saying the behavior is "right" or "wrong".

You do not have to manipulate the `originalValuesMap` to achieve your goal. Just change the sequence. Try this:

```
var foo = manager.createEntity('Foo', {
        id = targetId
    }, breeze.EntityState.Unchanged);  // create as if freshly queried

foo.bar = 'new value';  // also sets 'originalValues' and changes the EntityState

manager.saveChanges(); // etc.
```

Let us know if that does the trick.

Comment: my bad, I should know this by now.  That worked perfectly.  The key was that it needed to be in the Unchanged state before any updates were made to the entity.  I was creating it in Added state then setting modified myself, which is just wrong.  That probably confused the EF backend with a state of Modifed and no OV map, kinda like a combination of an Add and an Update. Thanks once again!